# How can I implement logical or for existence of one of a list of member functions in a 'requires' expression?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have a generic function which can accept types which have at least one of a list of member functions.

I am trying to write an inline requires expression to validate this.

I have an example below which fails to compile because neither of my types pass the *requires* clause

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    bool has_foo() const { return true; }
};

struct Bar
{
    bool has_bar() const { return true; }
};


template<typename T>
bool check(const T& t)
    requires requires (T t)
    {
        { t.has_foo() || t.has_bar() };
    }
{
    if constexpr (requires { t.has_foo(); })
    {
        if (t.has_foo())
            std::cout << "has foo\n";
        else
            std::cout << "no foo\n";
    }
    if constexpr (requires { t.has_bar(); })
    {
        if (t.has_bar())
            std::cout << "has bar\n";
        else
            std::cout << "no bar\n";
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    check(Foo());
    check(Bar());
    return 0;
}
```

The build fails due to:

```
test.cpp:40:10: error: no matching function for call to 'check(Foo)'
   40 |     check(Foo());
      |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~
test.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T> bool check(const T&) requires requires(T t) {{t.has_foo() || t.has_bar()};}'
   15 | bool check(const T& t)
      |      ^~~~~
test.cpp:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:15:6: note: constraints not satisfied
test.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class T> bool check(const T&) requires requires(T t) {{t.has_foo() || t.has_bar()};} [with T = Foo]':
test.cpp:40:10:   required from here
test.cpp:15:6:   required by the constraints of 'template<class T> bool check(const T&) requires requires(T t) {{t.has_foo() || t.has_bar()};}'
test.cpp:16:14:   in requirements with 'T t' [with T = Foo]
test.cpp:18:23: note: the required expression '(t.has_foo() || t.has_bar())' is invalid, because
   18 |         { t.has_foo() || t.has_bar() };
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:18:28: error: 'struct Foo' has no member named 'has_bar'
   18 |         { t.has_foo() || t.has_bar() };
      |                          ~~^~~~~~~
```

How can I turn my requires expression

```
requires (T t)
{
    { t.has_foo() || t.has_bar() };
}
```

into a logical or expression, such that types which meet *either* of the expressions are allowed?

Comment: Interesting, haven't been aware that concepts can be used in `if constexpr`... Always learning something new ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah, can make for really clean generic code!

Comment: @Aconcagua: learned this trick yesterday form video: 'C++ Weekly - Ep 368 - The Power of template-template Parameters: A Basic Guide' (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6Cub7EFLXo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split it into two requires expressions, which can be combined with logical OR:

```
template<typename T>
bool check(const T& t)
    requires(
        requires (T t) { t.has_foo(); } ||
        requires (T t) { t.has_bar(); }
        )
{
    // [...]
}
```

If that looks too convoluted, you can also define that as a new concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_foo_or_bar =
    requires (T t) { t.has_foo(); } ||
    requires (T t) { t.has_bar(); };

template<typename T>
bool check(const T& t)
    requires( has_foo_or_bar<T>(t) )
{
    // [...]
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nWKsnhY5v)

Comment: For the record, `(...)` are redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You can write two distinct concepts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

struct Foo
{
    bool foo() const { return true; }
};

struct Bar
{
    bool bar() const { return true; }
};

template<typename T>
concept has_foo = requires (T t)
{ { t.foo() } -> std::same_as<bool>; };

template<typename T>
concept has_bar = requires (T t)
{ { t.bar() } -> std::same_as<bool>; };
```

Then, you could either add another concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept has_foo_or_bar = has_bar<T> or has_foo<T>;
```

Or use those separately:

```
template<typename T>
bool check(const T& t)
    requires  has_foo<T> or has_bar<T>
{
    if constexpr ( has_foo<T> )
    {
        // ...
    }
    if constexpr ( has_bar<T> )
    {
        //  ...
    }
    // ...
}
```